# Does Swift have an equivalent to Rust's `uninitialized`?

Tags: swift, optimization, initialization, llvm

The Rust standard library has the [`std::mem::uninitialized`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.uninitialized.html) function, which allows you to manually create an undefined (and possible invalid) value of any type. This essentially maps to LLVM's [`undef`](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#undefined-values). I was wondering if Swift had an equivalent, as I haven't been able to find one skimming through the standard library documentation.

#### Motivation

The primary use for this is to bypass the compiler's normal memory initialization checks when they prove imprecise. For instance, you might want to initialize some members of a structure using methods (or in Swift's case, property setters), which the compiler usually would not allow you to do. Using dummy values works, but that's potentially less efficient (if the optimizer cannot prove that the dummy is meaningless).

In Rust, `uninitialized` values are treated as initialized by the initialization checker, but as uninitialized by LLVM, leading to more reliable optimization. Since the Swift compiler is also built atop LLVM, it seems like something the Swift compiler should also be able to support.

#### My Specific Use Case

I have a `struct` which encapsulates a set of bit fields compacted into one machine word (an unsigned integer type). The `struct` type provides a safe and convenient interface for reading and modifying the individual fields, through computed properties.

I also have an initializer that takes the relevant field values as parameters. I could initialize the underlying machine word using the same  bitwise operations that the computed properties use (in which case I would be repeating myself), or I could initialize it simply by setting the values of the computed properties.

Currently, Swift does not support using computed properties before `self` has been fully initialized. It's also unlikely Swift will ever support this case, since the computed property setters modify the existing machine word, which would require it to already be initialized, at least as far as Swift is concerned. Only *I* know that all my setters, in concert, will fully initialize that machine word.

My current solution is to simply initialize the machine word to `0`, and then run the setters. Since a constant `0` is trivially absorbed into the bitwise `|` chain that combines the fields, there's no CPU time lost, but that's always going to be the case. This is the kind of situation where, in Rust, I would have used an `uninitialized` value to express my intent to the optimizer.

Comment: Not familiar with Rust, but maybe an `UnsafePointer`/`UnsafeMutablePointer`?

Comment: If I understand you correctly do you mean `Lazy initialisations` in swift?

Comment: @JoshCaswell I don't think so? `UnsafePointer` and its siblings *can* bypass Swift's normal initialization checks during reads, but the only transitively. You can make Swift assume that something referred to through a pointer is initialized, even if it wasn't, but then you'd still need to be able to create `undef` memory for the pointer to reference. And then you potentially lose the optimizations associated with compiler-intrinsic `undef`s, as Swift is assuming that the memory has some value it doesn't know, not that the memory could have any value the compiler wants it to.

Comment: @DominikBucher I don't think lazy initialization would accomplish what I want. Mostly, I'm looking to be able to call member methods within an initializer before all the stored data members have been properly initialized, where those member methods take care of the rest of the initialization; it's all to stay DRY. I'll add more disambiguating detail to the question.

Comment: Been googling a while, if you didn't asked here maybe it is worth your while:

 https://www.reddit.com/r/swift/comments/6no0o8/create_uninitialized_memory_on_the_stack/

Comment: Interesting. An implicitly unwrapped optional is usually how you express "damn your rules, I know this won't be accessed before it's set". I'm not sure whether that's usable here, though.